# Регулярное выражение без запятой

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка, которая ищет конструкции `слово|слово1|слово2` в тексте,

```
(\S+\|\S+\|\S+)
```

Как изменить эту регулярку так, чтобы символы сразу после (например, `слово|слово1|слово2,` ) игнорировались?

PS: Пробывал `(\w+\|\w+\|\w+)`, но тут вылезла проблема с тем, что такое выражение не понимает кириллицу

Comment: Пример применения этого выражения имеется? Например в жаве есть как минимум две функции: одна для поиска выражения, которая проигнорирует лишние буквы, другая для полного соответствия, которая при наличии лишних букв никакого соответствия не найдёт. Сами забейте своё выражение и тестируемую строку в http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html и в таблице результатов колонки matches() и find() Так что дело совсем не в выражении, а в способе его применения. На каком языке программируете, что он не понимает кириллицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Регулярное выражение без запятой

Можно воспользоваться символьным классом с отрицанием:

```
([^\s,]+\|[^\s,]+\|[^\s,]+)
```

`[^\s,]` - любой не пробельный символ и не запятая.

Тест https://regex101.com/r/INEWVY/1

Работает в php, js, python и golang (если тест не врет).

Comment: Спасибо! Это точно работает в js ;)

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не заменить разделители пробельными символами и просто вывести потом всю строку:

`select regexp_substr(regexp_replace('слово|слово1|слово2', '[|]', ' '), 
                     '[a-zа-я0-9]+([\ |])[a-zа-я0-9]+\1[a-zа-я0-9]+')
 from dual`

написано на Oracle

Comment: или разделители не надо убирать?) тогда вместо regexp_replace('слово|слово1|слово2', '[|]', ' ') просто 'слово|слово1|слово2'